# Android LinearLayout doesn't update properly

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I'm having trouble with one of my first android applications. What I'm trying to do is make a dynamic `HorizontalScrollView`, which's content will come from a list that can change over time (like a list of devices in range or something similar).

The trouble is that it doesn't work when the list gets empty. After that, the view displays the one item that was there before disappearance. It works fine when an item appears on the list. The following method is called when an element is either added to or deleted from the list.

Maybe I'm missing something really elementary. I would like the list to go empty whenever the list gets empty

I would appreciate some hints towards the solution (and some criticism as well, if the code is androidwise terrible)

```
    protected void updateSlideMenu() {
        HorizontalScrollView slideMenu = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        /* 
         * ...
         * Here's some code that gets data into list
         */
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.removeAllViews();
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        if(slideMenu == null) {
            Log.d("slideMenu is null in", "updateSlideMenu");
            return;
        }
        slideMenu.removeAllViews();
        slideMenu.addView(ll);
        for (String str: list) {
            Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setText(str);
            b.setOnClickListener(/*...*/);
            ll.addView(b);
        }
        slideMenu.refreshDrawableState();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Adaptors

```
ArrayAdapter<Button> buttons =new ArrayAdapter<Button>
//add buttons to this variable
l1.setAdaptor(buttons);
```

after you added the buttons call this method 
`buttons.notifyDatasethasChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llParent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private LinearLayout llParent;
    private HorizontalScrollView slideMenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        slideMenu = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        llParent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llParent);


    }

    protected void updateSlideMenu() {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        /*
         * ...
         * Here's some code that gets data into list
         */
        llParent.removeAllViews();
        if(slideMenu == null) {
            Log.d("slideMenu is null in", "updateSlideMenu");
            return;
        }
        for (String str: list) {
            Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setText(str);
            b.setOnClickListener(/*...*/);
            llParent.addView(b);
        }
        slideMenu.refreshDrawableState();
    }
}
```

Call **updateSlideMenu** method wherever you want to update your horizontal scrollview.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `RecyclerView` as the are great for tasks of this kind and it makes it really simple. You could find info about how to use it here https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

The approach with LinearLayout is bad because it doesn't recycle views. Meaning that if you will have 20 items, but you display only 5, the rest 15 will sit there and waste your memory, meanwhile `RecyclerView` will reuse the Views and manage the memory